# how to change the grayscale of an image with javascript in the "current page"?

Tags: javascript, css

This question is concerned about the usage of javascript to chnage the grayscale of the image in the "`current link`" in navigation.

In the following navigation bar, there are four squares with the corresponding colors. Their grayscale is supposed to change when hover, focus and active and also, the grayscale of the current page should change and I have tried to do it with the js graying function to *show which page we are in*. But the the java script code is not working and only the first page changes its grayscale by the js code

```js
var current = document.getElementById('default');

function graying(el) {
  if (current != null) {
    current.className = "";
  }
  el.className = "graying";
  current = el;
}
```

```css
#nav {
  width: 100px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 100px auto;
}
#nav img:active,
#nav img:focus,
#nav img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  filter: gray;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
}
#nav img.graying {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: gray;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="blue.html">
      <img id="default" class="graying" onclick="graying(this);" src="images/red.png">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="green.html">
      <img onclick="graying(this);" src="images/green.png">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="red.html">
      <img onclick="graying(this);" src="images/blue.png">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="yellow.html">
      <img onclick="graying(this);" src="images/yellow.png">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

. Is it correct to use "onclick" in this case?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is `filter:gray`? That's not any CSS I'm aware of...and it's probably overriding the correct property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```css
img {
  filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
  filter: grayscale(1); /* Microsoft Edge and Firefox 35+ */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */
}

/* Disable grayscale on hover */
img:hover {
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/630/170/">
```

Comment: Thanks but my question was on the js code and how I can indicate the page I am in with the color of the icon in the navigation. Not the garyscale.